# If statement code clarification

Tags: c#

Would someone be able to explain to me the meaning of this code?

```
private long GCD(long a, long b) {
            return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);
        }
```

If zero, then b is equal to a.  Else `GCD(b, a % b)`.  What exactly does if `0` mean here?  Or am I misinterpreting `return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);`

Comment: right it is c#, my mistake

Comment: Hmm, doesn't matter. `if` what??

Comment: my interpretation of the notation `return b == 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);`
is b is equal to a if zero, else GCD(b, a % b).  Is this a valid statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got your order of operations wrong; `?:` has the lowest priority here. The code is equivalent to the following:

```
if (b == 0)
    return a;
else
    return GCD(b, a % b);
```

Comment: Ah, now I see.  I think i thought that it was `return b = 0 ? a : GCD(b, a % b);`  in which it was assigning b a value.  At least that is what i've been taught in c++.

Answer (score 1):

> If zero, then b is equal to a. Else GCD(b, a % b). What exactly does if 0 mean here?

Nope, read the code like the below:

```
return ( (b == 0) ? a : GCD(b, a % b)  )  ;
```

How you should be reading the code is:

- If b is equal to zero, then the function should return `0`
- Else the function should return the value of (recursive function) call with parameters -- b & a%b